# Playing a song in bash with a link

Tags: bash, audio, background

Can I play a song in the background of my bash game using a link to the audio?

I’ve tried looking it up but all I come up with is that I must use and mp3 file.

Answer (score 0):

For sure.
take a look on mplyer, vlc and some others, as described in this Ask Ubuntu [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/193737/how-to-listen-radio-from-terminal).

Regards